# Creating a dataframe from JSON data using PYSPARK

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a dataframe out of json data using pyspark module ,but not able to do,tried doing it with sqlContext.read.json but not getting proper result.

sample json data:

```
{
"userId":"rirani",
"jobTitleName":"Developer",
"firstName":"Romin",
"lastName":"Irani",
"preferredFullName":"Romin Irani",
"employeeCode":"E1",
"region":"CA",
"phoneNumber":"408-1234567",
"emailAddress":"romin.k.irani@gmail.com"
},
{
"userId":"nirani",
"jobTitleName":"Developer",
"firstName":"Neil",
"lastName":"Irani",
"preferredFullName":"Neil Irani",
"employeeCode":"E2",
"region":"CA",
"phoneNumber":"408-1111111",
"emailAddress":"neilrirani@gmail.com"
}
{
"userId":"thanks",
"jobTitleName":"Program Directory",
"firstName":"Tom",
"lastName":"Hanks",
"preferredFullName":"Tom Hanks",
"employeeCode":"E3",
"region":"CA",
"phoneNumber":"408-2222222",
"emailAddress":"tomhanks@gmail.com"
}
```

expected o/p:in table format.can anyone help me this.

Comment: And what result are you getting? What does _o/p:in_ mean?

Answer (score 2):

You can do use SparkSession:

```
my_json = [{ 
     "userId":"rirani",
    "jobTitleName":"Developer", 
    "firstName":"Romin", 
    "lastName":"Irani", 
    "preferredFullName":"Romin Irani",
     "employeeCode":"E1",
     "region":"CA",
     "phoneNumber":"408-1234567",
     "emailAddress":"romin.k.irani@gmail.com" 
    }, 
    { "userId":"nirani", 
    "jobTitleName":"Developer", 
    "firstName":"Neil", 
    "lastName":"Irani",
    "preferredFullName":"Neil Irani",
    "employeeCode":"E2", "region":"CA",
    "phoneNumber":"408-1111111",
    "emailAddress":"neilrirani@gmail.com" 
    },
    { "userId":"thanks", 
    "jobTitleName":"Program Directory",
    "firstName":"Tom", 
    "lastName":"Hanks", 
    "preferredFullName":"Tom Hanks",         "employeeCode":"E3", "region":"CA", "phoneNumber":"408-2222222",
"emailAddress":"tomhanks@gmail.com"
         }]

json_df = spark.read.json(my_json)
json_df.show()
```